# Shiny - Plotly output not appearing in viewer

Tags: r, plot, shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

Got a few really tedious issue with Shiny Dashboard.

So, I've got three main plots and a input control panel, which span 2 fluidRows. I want to add another plot (Enq_Outcome) in a separate fluidRow, but having troubles displaying it in the viewer when loading the app.

In fact, there doesn't actually appear to be any problems with the code (at least R is not flagging it up when I run the code) and the rest of the app appears to load properly without any error messages (most of it anyway). So I'm not entirely sure why my new plot (Enq_Outcome) is not appearing.

In addition to this, two of my plots (Time_Ser) and (Response) don't initiate the default plot when loading the app, e.g. so the selected = " " argument doesn't appear to work for my radioButtons and dateRangeInput inputs.

Any help with this would be great as it's been puzzling me for ages.

**ui.r**

```
  ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "red",
  dashboardHeader(title = "iReport",
                  titleWidth = 500),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # Tab for Dashboard
      tabItem(tabName = "Dashboard"),
      # Tab for Survey Analytics
      tabItem(tabName = "Survey"),
      #Tab for Enquiry Analytics
      tabItem(tabName = "Enquiries"),
      #Tab for Web Analytics
      tabItem(tabName = "Metrics"),
      #Tab for Twitter Analytics
      tabItem(tabName = "Twitter")
    ),

    # Row 1 objects
    fluidRow(
      # Value boxes
      valueBox(
        479,
        "Total No. of Enquiries",
        color = "green",
        icon = icon("commenting")
      ),
      valueBox(
        1.7,
        "Average response time",
        color = "blue",
        icon = icon("exchange")
      ),
      valueBox(
        "98%",
        "Percentage satisfied customers",
        color = "orange",
        icon = icon("thumbs-up")
      )
    ),

    # Row 2 objects
    fluidRow(box(
      width = 12, plotlyOutput("Time_Ser", height = "400px")
    )),

    # Row 3 objects
    fluidRow(
      # Data visualisations 1
      box(width = 5, plotlyOutput("Enq_Num", height = "500px")),
      box(
        width = 2,
        h2("Control panel"),
        dateRangeInput(
          "date",
          "Date:",
          label = h4("Choose a time frame"),
          start = "2017-05-02",
          end = "2017-07-30",
          min = "2017-05-02",
          max = "2017-06-30",
          startview = "2017-06-30"
        ),
        selectInput(
          "select",
          "Select",
          label = h4("Select a month"),
          choices = c("May", "June")
        ),
        radioButtons(
          "area",
          "Area",
          label = h4("Response Time by Team"),
          choices = list("PEU", "DAU", "MSU", "PRO", "MISC"),
          selected = "PEU"
        )),
      box(width = 5, plotlyOutput("Response", height = "500px"))),

    #Row 4 Objects
    fluidRow(# Data visualisations 2
      box(width = 5, plotlyOutput("Enq_Outcome")),
      box(
        width = 2,
        selectInput(
          "outcome",
          "Outcome",
          label = h4("Enquiry outcomes by output area"),
          choices = list("Link", "Clarified", "CM", "Unavailable", "Referred")
        )))))
```

**server.r**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Reactive date input for Tim_Ser
  Time2 <- Time
  reactiveTime <- reactive({
    Time2 %>% filter(Date.received >= input$date[1] &
                       Date.received < input$date[2])})

  # DATA
  Numbers <-
    data.frame(
      May = c(73, 26, 23, 10, 23),
      June = c(144, 28, 21, 20, 33),
      areas = c("PEU", "MIG", "DAU", "MISC", "PRO")
    )
  Time <- data.frame(date = c("2017-05-02","2017-05-03","2017-05-04", "2017-05-05","2017-05-07"), n = c(14,11,7,12,14))
  Respond <-
    data.frame(
      DAU = c(32, 14, 8),
      MIG = c(51, 7, 4),
      MISC = c(42, 41, 3),
      PEU = c(135, 16, 18),
      PRO = c(32, 15, 2),
      Days = c("1-2 Days", "3-4 Days", "5+ Days")
    )
  rownames(Respond) <- c("1-2 Days", "3-4 Days", "5+ Days")

  Outcome <-
    data.frame(
      Area = c("DAU", "PEU", "PRO", "MSU", "MISC"),
      CLAR = c(5, 23, 2, 2, 13),
      LINK = c(45, 4, 23, 24, 18),
      UNAV = c(1, 13, 15, 11, 12),
      CM = c(8, 15, 3, 10, 2),
      REF = c(26, 24, 11, 7, 12)
    )

  # OUTPUTS

  output$Time_Ser <- renderPlotly({
    Time_Ser <-
      plot_ly(reactiveTime(),
              x = Date.received,
              y = n,
              mode = "lines") %>%
      layout(title = "Q3. Enquiries over Time")

  })

  output$Enq_Num <- renderPlotly({
    selector <- switch(input$select,
                       "May" = Numbers$May,
                       "June" = Numbers$June)

    Enq_Num <- plot_ly(
      Numbers,
      x = areas,
      y = selector,
      type = "bar",
      color = areas
    ) %>%
      layout(
        title = "Q3. Enquiries by Output Team by Month",
        xaxis = list(title = "Output Team", showgrid = F),
        yaxis = list(title = "No. Enquiries")
      )

  })

  output$Response <- renderPlotly({
    if (is.null(input$area))
      return()
    area.select <- switch(
      input$area,
      "PEU" = Respond$PEU,
      "DAU" = Respond$DAU,
      "MSU" = Respond$MIG,
      "PRO" = Respond$PRO,
      "MISC" = Respond$MISC
    )

    Response <- plot_ly(
      Respond,
      labels = Days,
      values = area.select,
      type = "pie",
      rotation = 180,
      direction = "clockwise",
      hole = 0.6
    ) %>%
      layout(title = "Q3. Response Time")
  })

  output$Enq_Outcome <- renderPlotly({
    enq.outcome <- switch(
      input$outcome,
      "Clarified" = Outcome$CLAR,
      "Link" = Outcome$LINK,
      "CM" = Outcome$CM,
      "Unavailable" = Outcome$UNAV,
      "Referred" = Outcome$REF
    )
    Enq_Outcome <- renderPlotly(
      Outcome,
      y = Area,
      x = enq.outcome,
      type = "bar",
      colour = Area
    )
  })

}
```

***Run App***

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: it does throw an error for me. `object time not found` or the 'if condition is not logical`

Comment: @user5249203 Sorry I should have included the code for the Time dataframe:               
                                                             'Time <- data.frame(date = c("2017-05-02","2017-05-03","2017-05-04", 
   "2017-05-05","2017-05-07"), n = c(14,11,7,12,14))'

Comment: Now when I re-run the code I get the following: "Error in if (inline) { : argument is not interpretable as logical"